# Slicing a 2D numpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What's wrong with the code below?

```
arr=numpy.empty((2,2))
arr[0:,0:]=1
print(arr[1:,1:])
arr=([ [1, 2, 3], [ 4, 5, 6], [ 7, 8, 9] ])
print(arr[1:2, 1])
```

I am getting the following error and not able to slice the array( fifth line). Please help me with this.

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple.

Comment: array[1][1]. I just want to do this by slicing method but not able to to so.

Answer (score 1):

You rebind the name `arr` to point to a Python `list` in your fourth line, and so your question title doesn't quite fit: you're not slicing a 2d numpy array.  `list`s can't be sliced the way that numpy arrays can.  Compare:

```
>>> arr= numpy.array([ [1, 2, 3], [ 4, 5, 6], [ 7, 8, 9] ])
>>> arr
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> arr[1:2, 1]
array([5])
```

but

```
>>> arr.tolist()
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> arr.tolist()[1:2, 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-23-4a441cf2eaa9>", line 1, in <module>
    arr.tolist()[1:2, 1]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

`arr=([ [1, 2, 3], [ 4, 5, 6], [ 7, 8, 9] ])` is a `python list`,not a `numpy array`.

You reassign `arr` with  `arr=([ [1, 2, 3], [ 4, 5, 6], [ 7, 8, 9] ])` to a list.

Make it a numpy array:

```
In [37]: arr  = numpy.array([ [1, 2, 3], [ 4, 5, 6], [ 7, 8, 9] ])

In [38]: arr
Out[38]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [39]: (arr[1:2, 1])
Out[39]: array([5])
```